# How to a load text file using Ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery

How to load a .txt file using Ajax? I only found how to load XML files.

This is what I have so far:

```
function loadTxt(url)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    var txt;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
           document.getElementById("phones").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","folder",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

And then:

> ```
> <form name="phoneBook">
>             <p id="phones"></p>
>             <input type="button" onClick="loadTxt()" value="Click">
> </form>
> ```

But nothing happens.
This is my first time working with Ajax, so a detailed answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't ask people to write code for you. It's your assignment/job, so show what code you have written so far and describe what problems you encountered.

Comment: Where are you trying to load it ? on the browser ? Can you show the reference you used to load the xml file ? getting a text file should be similar.

Comment: i want to take the data and display it

Comment: The process of loading a text file is the same as loading an XML file. You say you can manage to load an XML file, just do the same thing.

Comment: can't manage, just saw an example. here is what i've done so far

Answer (score 0):

You haven't opened a connection to the server using

```
XHR.open("GET", urlToYourTextFile, true);
```

After a connection is open, you must call send() to actually send the request.

Comment: I changed xmlhttp to XHR, nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry brother, by XHR I meant an XMLHttpRequest object, which in your case is **xmlhttp**. BTW what is folder in this line: `xmlhttp.open("GET","folder",true);` The second argument to open must be the URL of your text file, something like localhost:8080/file.txt or file.txt if your source file is in the same directory.

Comment: the url... :) so i do have xmlhttp.. any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Please check your URL. "folder" doesn't seem to be a valid URL

Comment: it goes: //something/something/file.txt

Comment: Then please check your browser's console to find the error. Developer Tools/Firebug, under the network tab